# What's the easiest way to write a properly working onChange handler for lightning:recordForm?

Tags: lightning-aura-components, lightning-record-form

It is more question for Salesforce gurus and Lightning/Aura Components Framework developers.

On my own, Lightning Framework has a lot of restrictions and sometimes it is really hard to build flexible things. Every day I do Lightning Components development and I often encounter in situations that block me. And one of them is `onChange` handler for record form.

What's the easiest way to write a *properly wokring* `onChange` event for `lightning:recordForm`?

Comment: Hi Ruslan, please take a moment to scroll through the [tour] and read [ask]. As written, this question is nearly certain to be closed as off topic. What some people find hard, others find a breeze, and vice versa. Asking if something is hard is purely based on opinion.

Answer (score 3):

`lightning:recordForm` doesn't support the `onchange` event.  If you think about it, it makes sense:  you're usually interested in seeing when a *field* changes, not when the form as a whole changes.

All of the lightning:inputX type fields support the onchange event.  (`lightning:input`, `lightning:inputAddress`, `lightning:inputField`, ...)

I hope this helps make Lightning coding a little bit easier for you  :)

Comment: Hey! Thank you for your help! But, could you show how to bind a myRecord record attribute to the lightning:recordForm record attribute? Because, as I know lightning:recordForm uses Lightning Data Service under the hood and I can't imagine how to combine your solution with it.
Thanks!

Comment: Oh no!  You're right.  I was thinking of lightning:dataTable.  Been working with that this week.  Oops!  I'll edit my answer.

Comment: So tell me about your use case.  I wonder whether there's another way to approach it.

Comment: I have a component that contains `lightning:recordForm`. It should handle all changes made to `recordForm` record and send this information to the parent using Component event. The `recordForm` component has (undocumented) `onChange` handler, but its callback receives only a value that set on a changed field (`{"value": ""}`). But for my use case, I have to know what field was changed or to get whole changed record object.

Comment: Would including a "submit" button be an option?  If so, you could override the default onsubmit event, and send the values to the parent component that way.

Comment: Thanks for suggestion Shane! But, it isn't appropriate in my case, I display the form in a Modal window and with that, I display custom Cancel and Submit buttons in the footer of the Modal. 
For here - another issue is when you submit a form with JS (`component.find('recordForm').submit()`) it won't call `onSubmit` handler, which is ridiculous. It means that they assign custom user `onSubmit` callback on the form button and not on the form itself... (facepalm)

Comment: Yep.  I ran into that one recently myself.  Meh.